# Knockout Validation success classes?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout-2.0, knockout-validation

I am using [Knockout Validation](https://github.com/ericmbarnard/Knockout-Validation) and have everything working as I wanted.  I am using it with Twitter Bootstrap and have the proper classes being set when an error is encountered.

With jQuery Validation, I was able to also set classes when a validated element passed validation.  For instance, you could turn the input box green when the user had entered valid information.

Is there a way to do that with Knockout Validation?  Anyone have an example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently, Knockout-Validation doesn't support a "validationSuccess" class to be added to an element if a validated value `isValid`. (But we do take pull requests).

However, if you simply want to indicate success on an element, you can do something like:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: lastName, css: { success: lastName.isModified() && lastName.isValid() }"/>
```

If you want this to be the default behavior, just look at overriding the
 `ko.bindingHandlers['validationMessage']` and 
`ko.bindingHandlers['validationElement']` functionality.

I've got an example working here (use JSBin in Chrome): http://jsbin.com/miqanineva/2/edit?html,css,js,output